# SharePoint 2010 multiple report viewer webparts - very slow

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I have 7 report viewer webparts on one SharePoint page. It takes ages to load all of them. If I open the RDL directly, the report loads within 2 seconds.  If I only load a single report viewer web part then the web part loads very fast too.

**How can I decrease the loading time?**

All those UpdatePanels that are created for lazy loading, AJAX calls, etc. cause part of the trouble. Disabling ViewState is not an option because it is breaking the web parts.

Comment: What is your reasoning for having 7 report viewer web parts on the same page?

Comment: We have developed +- 10 reports we want to expose on SharePoint pages. We have 4 pages, each for the corresponding role, with 5 - 8 report web parts, depending on the role.

Comment: Is the user having to scroll down the page to view each report?  If so, then why wouldn't you put the reports on separate pages (1 per page) and have them use the navigation to view different reports?

Comment: We want to create a dashboard, so the whole idea is to present the user with multiple reports. Put them on separate pages is not an option. The whole idea behind web parts is that you can put more than one on a page, right... And 7 seems not very  much to me.

Comment: 7 web parts on a page are doable but I don't think reporting services was intended to be used to have 7 reports load on a page.  The load time can be slow sometimes for a single report so when running 7 you are probably asking for trouble.  Why don't you create your own dashboard webparts?  You will have much tighter control on how they render versus the built-in SSRS report web part rendering.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but another option might be to use KPIs instead of the full reports. It's much less information for a user to have to process and you can make it so they click on the individual KPI to bring up the relevant report (in a pop-up, if you want).

Comment: @RyanShripat has a good point. Another way is to look at some sql server side optimizations by looking at missing indexes might be the best approach here.

Comment: @skeletank Can you explain your comment in detail about creating own dashboard webpart

Comment: @MonicaJagani Instead of designing the interface for each dashboard control inside an SSRS report and then just throwing the report webpart on the page you should make a custom webpart (in C#/VB) for each dashboard control.  That way you can have tighter control on the html output and be able to see if the bottleneck is your database query or the html rendering of the SSRS web part.  This obviously depends on how complicated it would be to replicate what the SSRS report is doing.

Answer (score 3):

We've had the same problem over the years. SharePoint doesn't do well with multiple report viewer web parts.  It's frustrating, but not much can be done about it.  We found the best solution was to merge the different reports in a single report, essentially making the dashboard in the report itself.  This reduced the number of web parts to one or two.